# VBA Populate ComboBox with multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure this is straight forward but I have a combobox in userform which is giving me a dynamic list of values. It turns out that I now also need to bring in the column next to it. However with the code below it somehow seems to stack the values as one list:

```
i = 2

For Each c In Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    CB_Account.AddItem Cells(i, 3).Value
    CB_Account.AddItem Cells(i, 4).Value
    i = i + 1

Next
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting each item in the combobox to be ColumnC+ColumnD, or you want an array with Column C and Column D separately?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. ComboBox contains values from column C as well as column D.

Comment: `stack the values as one list`: yes, that's what your code is doing. Perhaps you need to better clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: Apologies rather than having them in one column, I'm trying to get them to come through as two columns next to each other in the drop down box. `ID Account` rather than one list returning ID, Account, ID, Account all together.